# Identify active slide in C#

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, office-interop

I would like to know which is the current slide viewed by the user in PowerPoint (in edition not presentation).
I used an `SlideChange event` with `var new Index = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex`.

The problem is when the cursor on the thumbnail panel on the left is not on a slide but between two. In that case, I have an error **View (unknown member) : Invalid request.  No slide is currently in view.** which is normal because there is no view pointed.
Unfortunately SlideChange event is also raised in that case.

I would like to ignore cases when there is no slide pointed. But I can't find any property that indicates it, so I could do something like `if(Application.ActiveWindow..... != ... ){doThis}`.

The only (bad) way I have found is to make a **try/catch** (but it slows the application, it is raised at each new slide with an exception). Do you have any idea to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to get the active slide object:

```
var slide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
```

Answer (score 2):

the below code is able to find which slide is currently viewed

`SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex`

but this will work for slideshow only

OR

use below code..i am not sure but it may help

```
if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Active == MsoTriState.msoTrue &&
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Panes[2].Active == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
        {
           bla bla
        }
```