# How to get current PowerPoint slide number

Tags: c#, powerpoint, com-interop

I am trying to access the current PPT slide index in normal view so that I can add a shape to the slide. But the VBA code for this has no equivalent that I can find in C#. Does anyone have the required syntax for finding the current slide index in the active presentation in normal mode? Thank you.

```
VBA code for retrieving the slide index:
idx = ActiveWindow.View.slide.SlideIndex
Set slide = ActivePresentation.Slides(idx)

C# code that is supposed to work in SlideShow mode from another SO post.
PowerPoint.SlideShowWindow.Presentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition

C# COM code for Normal mode that does not work is shown below. 
The only Intellisense options after .Slide are Equals, Hashcode, GetType, and ToString.

var idx = papp.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.?
```

Comment: The Slides object has the Index method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-12/ff760534(v=office.12)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, it does have the Index method, but you need to feed a SlideID into the Index method to select a slide. But I don't have a SlideID for the current slide.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50816648/identify-active-slide-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thank you again for your help. The link was interesting - it gave some syntax to get the slide directly, bypassing the problem of getting the index of the current slide. So, although it didn't solve my "get the index" problem, it did allow me to get to the slide. I had to cast the result of the syntax to a slide to get access to all the object methods in the slide.